# Filter Table VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing my project and I am encountering some problems. Moreover, my scope was to use VBA as a primary software to do my project.

As for now, I am hoping that I can use a drop down list to filter my table whereby it only shows the particular department and weeks I want to show.

From the image below, From the range("C7:L26"), whenever I filter cell(F2) or cell(J2), it will leave the data that I want from the dropdown list.

For example, if cell(F2) = 2 and cell J2 = e, From range("C7,L26"), it will only show department with value "e" and have week 2 in it. As for cells that does not have the department value or week value, it will be cleared or blank.

I also hope that if it is possible to press a button to return the table back to default.

Do guide me and I really need your help!!

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/SolTn.jpg [2]https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXfUS.jpg

Update: I have tried recording Macros

```
Sub Filter()
'
' Filter Macro
    Range("B9:BR38").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 32
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$9:$BR$38").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="e"

End Sub
```

Update 2: Instead of recording Macros, i decided to use a Textbox to filter my table data. However, i realised that my table is not filtering according to what i type in the Text Box.

```css
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim Text

Text = TextBox1.Value

    If Text <> "" Then
    Sheet2.Range("A5:AV26").AutoFilter
    Field = 1
    criteria = "text,_"
    visibledropdown = False
    
    Else
        Sheet2.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    End If


    
    
    
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any code available which you've tried so far?  It is easiest to help build on and correct issues, as this is not the place to have coding completed for you.

Comment: You can `.ShowAllData` if you want to keep the autofilter handy or `.AutoFilterMode = False` if you want go get rid of the autofilter.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped , i have update my codes as of now. However, i realised that my "second update" listed above, my table wasnt filtering. Could you help me and teach me what i did wrong? =(

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the parameters on the same line separated by commas and it is **Criteria1**, not criteria. If you want to hide the drop-down arrows, you need to do each individually. The code below only hides the dropdown for the field being filtered. If course, if you are only filtering one field then you could just use `Sheet2.Range("A5:A26")` since filtering goes across all columns.

```
If True Then
    Sheet2.Range("A5:AV26").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="text,_", VisibleDropDown:=False
Else
    If Sheet2.AutoFilterMode Then Sheet2.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
```

See [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi, how do i have multiple fields?